# How to refresh bootstrap thumbnails after manually remove some items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap thumbnails feature to show a media grid. The page allows deleting certain items, and I handle the deletion with jQuery remove() method. I kind of hope bootstrap can relayout the thumbnails, but it doesn't happen:(, so I have some 'holes' in the media grid.

Is there a way to refresh the thumbnails to relayout themselve? I am not asking for fancy sliding animations, just refreshing is OK.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're removing the entire LI element from the thumbnail grid, for example:

```
$('.close').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('li').remove();
})
```

Working demo: **http://bootply.com/66728**

Comment: Turns out I was removing the LI's child... Thanks, Skelly!